# BufferedReader and filling an int array

Tags: java, arrays, parsing, split, bufferedreader

I have an assignment that I'm having some issues with.

The program uses Buffered Reader and on previous assignments we always had user input on one line and split it using `.split("\\s+")`.  This assignment takes in *up to* 500 ints all on a separate line until it reaches null.

My problem is parsing the String input into an int array.  Usually I have a string array that I set equal to the `inputValue.split("\\s+")` but the professor said we only need one array (our int array) and I can't figure this out without somehow splitting the input because right now I'm not getting all the input into my int array.

```
int count = 0;
int intScoresArr[] = new int [500];
//String strArray[];

while((inputValues = BR.readLine()) != null) {
    for(int i = 0; i < inputValues.length(); i++) {
        intScoresArr[i] = Integer.parseInt(strArray[i]);
        count++;
    }
}
average = calcMean(intScoresArr, count);
System.out.println(NF.format(average));
```

Here is some input and what I'm expecting for output and what I'm actually getting when I loop through and print out the array.

```
input:
    1
    2
    3
    4
    5

output:
    count: 5
    intScouresArr = 5 0 0 0 0

expected output: 
    count: 5
    intScoresArr = 1 2 3 4 5
```

Comment: If each line contains just one number, then that's what `readLine()` will return. You can directly `parseInt()` the string returned by `readLine()` (`inputValues` in your case).

Comment: Did you try without the inner `for(int i = 0; i < inputValues.length(); i++)` loop? I don't see how that is useful (if there is only one number per line). Just add stuff into `intScoresArr[count]` within the `while`.

Comment: Oh ok!  That makes lots of sense.  Now that you point that out I can see why the for loop unnecessary haha.

Comment: I get confused by the most simple things!  Thank you!  If you add your answer as an answer I'll except it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are expecting a single integer per row, you don't need two nested loops; the outer `while` is enough:

```
int count = 0;
int intScoresArr[] = new int [500];
String line;

while((line = BR.readLine()) != null) {
    intScoresArr[count] = Integer.parseInt(line.trim());
    count++;
}
```

Comment: What's line.trim doing?  Also, why initialize line to null?

Comment: `line.trim()` removes leading and trailing whitespace from the line (which would cause `Integer.parseInt` to fail). If you're certain that the input doesn't contain extra whitespace, just use `Integer.parseInt(line)`. Initializing `line` to `null` is actually redundant here; I've edited it out for clarity.

Comment: Ok cool.  Thank you again, you've ended two hours of searching and experimenting!  I should've asked sooner